# problems connecting cloud9 and bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, cloud9-ide

I am trying to connect cloud9 to my bitbucket account.
I get to the stage were I have to grant cloud9 access to my bitbucket, I grant it and then I get a message "another account is already linked to account "nirdweck"". In bitBucket I see cloud9 as a consumer but on cloud9 I can't connect to my bitbucket account. if I  revoke cloude9 in bitbucket and do everything from scratch, I get the same result.
don't know if it's connected or not but my bitBucket account is also part of a team.
I have only one cloud9 account.
any idea?
thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 1):

seems like I was logged in from two different computers to one account and this made cloud9 think another account is linked to my bitbucket acount. Had to logout from both, login with bitbucket and give a false mail and then disconnect the account from bitbucket. 
Got great help from cloud9 support team

Answer (score 0):

If your bitbucket account is already linked to an account you should be able to log in to Cloud9 via bitbucket. Then once you're logged in to that old account you can deactivate bitbucket via the "Add-on services" area on the control panel homepage.

After that is done you'll be able to link your bitbucket account to your new account.